# VBA Define range after searching for a value

Tags: vba, excel

I have a sheet that contains a week number in column B. I am trying to create a macro which looks for the week number in Cell J2 (or using an inputbox) and then  finds the week number in column B selects the data in columns C-G and copies them over to sheet 2 (I can do the copying etc its defining the range i'm struggling with.) [Image of datasheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LARZt.png)

Here is the code which shows which info I need to copy and paste. I'm struggling to make it find the week number and then define the range. The code below just does week 4.

```
Sub Copy4()
'
' Copy Macro
' Week number
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B14:B17").Copy
    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("D3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
' Data Copy
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C14:G17").Copy
    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C4").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Range("B2:G7").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlBitmap
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take a look at the help on [asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) questions and in particular how to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: What have you tried?  Post your code...

Comment: I have updated the question. Sorry I'm new to this.

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub copy()
Dim CopySheet As Worksheet
Dim PasteSheet As Worksheet
Set CopySheet = Worksheets("Sheet2")
Set PasteSheet = Worksheets("Sheet3")

Dim tableMaxCol As Integer
Dim tableMaxRow As Integer

Dim weekNumber As Integer

Dim row As Integer

tableMaxCol = CopySheet.Cells(1, CopySheet.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
tableMaxRow = CopySheet.Cells(CopySheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row

weekNumber = CopySheet.Cells(2, 10).Value

For row = 2 To tableMaxRow step 4
    If CopySheet.Cells(row, 2).Value = weekNumber Then
        CopySheet.Range(CopySheet.Cells(row, 3), CopySheet.Cells(row + 3, 7)).copy _
            Destination:=PasteSheet.Range("C4")
    End If
Next row
End Sub
```

Answer edited.

Comment: This locates a line and copies just that one row, I need it to copy the 3 rows as shown in the image and paste special values to cell C4 of sheet 2

Comment: Thanks Junyang. Only issue I have now is that this doesn't just paste the Values, everything else works fine though. I'll have a play and see how i can get it to just do the values.

Comment: Which I have now done and it works perfectly. you sir are a legend